# How do I install AWS PHP SDK on Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, composer-php, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I try composer with composer.json in /home/ec2-user but get the error:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - The requested package aws/aws-sdk-php could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.
```

My json file looks like this:

```
{
    "require": {
        "aws/aws-sdk-php": "2.*"
    }
}
```

I would like to try it in the project directory but don't know how to find this?

Answer (score 1):

The right way to install the php aws sdk is:

```
"aws/aws-sdk-php": "2.4.*@dev"
```

More info on packagist: https://packagist.org/packages/aws/aws-sdk-php

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Can I just use composer.json it in any directory?

Comment: What do you mean? composer install all the dependencies in to a vendor folder

Comment: Sorry I'm really new to this, I don't know what the vendor folder is, I just have composer.json in the /home/ec2-user directory and it's stil getting the same error?

Comment: at the moment im just uploading the site via zip and not using git yet

Comment: Composer is not for deploy your website but is for install dependencies that your project needs. All the installed dependencies goes to a vendor folder. After the composer install (first time) or composer update you can start using AWS for your PHP project just including the autoload.php file (is inside the vendor folder)

Comment: thanks again, im getting the same error with the new json file, its just in /home/ec2-user but i guess that doens't make any difference? do you know where the vendor folder is? sorry for amateur questions! might try to restart my instance as composer.phar wil only run now if i copy it into the same directory

Comment: Just create a composer.json with your code and my modification in your require array. After that run composer.phar install. The vendor folder will be (automatically composer create this dir) in the same place than your composer.json

Comment: Thanks for you help Mauro - even with the change it is still not working though, so confusing

Comment: must need something else too?

Comment: Just follow the requirements and the installation guide on http://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#installation

Comment: thanks, i was sshing to the server am i supposed to do it locally and then push it?

Comment: You can do that directly in the server

Comment: thanks so much for your help it was the git that i was missing i was just uploading a zip through beanstalk to test, but composer wouldn't run without git/repository being in place

Comment: Beanstalk is the git repository server... you can't sshing in to beanstalk (for try composer I mean). Works in your local environment?